# Display and edit file through jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, jenkins, configuration-management

I have some json and python configuration files in my aws environment which needs to be edited or modified on a daily basis. My intention is to write a job in jenkins which can pull the current file from the server and use an editor to make the changes and then upload the file back to the server. Is this possible at all through jenkins?

Or I can pull the file from S3 bucket and then make the changes and upload back to s3.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can get the file from S3 using [S3 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin), change it using awk or sed or anything similar and then publish it back using the same plugin.